# Upgrade VB6 to .net NewIndex & OLE1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb6, ole, vb6-migration

I am trying to get my conversion fixed from a VB6 application over to a VB.net 2010 application. Everything went well but for a few sleeted **listbox NewIndex** and **OLE control**.

Below are the trouble lines that could not seem to be converted:

```
VB6.SetItemData(lstARCurrent, lstARCurrent.NewIndex, (.Fields("approval_s").Value))
OLE1.CreateLink(strFileName)
OLE1.DoVerb(vbOLEOpen)
```

If anyone has any incite to correct this issue then that would be great as i have not found a way around these errors!

Thanks!

David

Comment: Do you get a compilation error message or a runtime exception message? Can you post the exact wording of any messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird.  In VB6 you'd do this:

```
lstARCurrent.Add(someString)
lstARCurrent.ItemData(lstARCurrent.NewIndex) = myLongKey
```

That was a nice way to store a string into a list box but associate a database ID with it.

I assume your `VB6.SetItemData` routine is doing the same thing. However, in .NET that won't work.  For one thing, items in list boxes in VB6 are 1 based instead of 0 based, so that'd probably cause issues, but the .NET list box most likely doesn't have a `.NewIndex` property.  Neither does a listbox have an `ItemData` array property.

The new way to handle this is to add an entire object and let the `.ToString` method tell the listbox what to display (sorry for C#, my VB.Net is rusty):

```
class MyItem
{
    public int MyKey { get; set; }
    public string MyStringValue { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.MyStringValue;
    }
}
```

Then just add the item:

```
lstARCurrent.Items.Add(new MyItem() { MyKey = 3, MyStringValue = "abc" });
```

It will display `abc` but you can use `lstARCurrent.SelectedItem` to get back the `MyItem` object.